# cardinality of multiplication of groups A,B when $A\leq B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cardinals

if $A$ and $B$ are infinite groups and

$$
|A|\leq|B|,
$$

where $|{}\cdot{}|$ denotes the group cardinality, is it right to say that  $|A|\cdot|B| = |B|$?

Comment: How about $A=B=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: If $B$ has infinite cardinality and $A \neq \emptyset$ (which is true if $A$ is a group), then $|A||B|=\max\{|A|,|B|\}=|B|$ since $|A| \leq |B|$. But this does not hold when $A$ and $B$ are finite.

Comment: I meant inifinite groups. how can I prove this? thanks

Comment: If you mean infinite groups, then you should edit the question to say what you mean, please.

Comment: @KIMKES1232 It has nothing to do with them being groups, this is true of all sets. See [cardinal multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_multiplication).

Comment: Group, or *set*?

Comment: @kccu: I suspect that this is a translation error.

Comment: thank you! but where can I find a proof for it? if you know